# Unable to understand a statement for congruences.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

It is  stated that in general, cannot reduce a congruence modulo a prime power into smaller moduli. What is the meaning implied by a prime power? What can be the reason for that?
This problem is stated in context of the statement below:

$a\equiv b \pmod 8 \implies a \equiv b \pmod4 \wedge a \equiv b \pmod2 $, but not converse.

I could not find a connect between the statement and the problem given.

Comment: I don't see a problem here.  What is "the problem given"?

Comment: @MatthewConroy It is the statement given for non-reduction of a congruence modulo prime power into smaller moduli that is not understood by me. Also, the connect with the given example is not understood. The statement is given at the end of a section.

Comment: I still do not understand what you are asking.  If $a \equiv b$ mod $p^k$, then $a \equiv b$ mod $p^m$ for all $m<k$.  Do you understand why the converse is not true? The "meaning implied by a prime power"  is an integer power of a prime number.  I do no not know what "that" refers to in your question "What can be the reason for that?".  Where is it "stated in general"?

Comment: @MatthewConroy This is given in book titled: Number Theory with Computer Applications, by Ramanujachary Kumanduri, Cristina Romero, pg. #65. Before the statement, there are: (i) Prop. 3.1.10: If $(m,n)=1$, then $a \equiv b \pmod m$ & $a \equiv b \pmod n \iff a\equiv b\pmod {mn}$. (with proof), (ii) Example 3.1.11. (1). If $a \equiv b \pmod {12}$ is equivalent to $a \equiv b \pmod 4$ and $a \equiv b \pmod 3$. (2). If $p,$ and $q$ are distinct primes and $a$ is an integer s.t. $a^2 \equiv 1 \pmod {pq}$. This congruence is satisfied iff $a^2 \equiv 1 \pmod p$ & $a^2 \equiv 1 \pmod q$.

Comment: Okay, could you please give the exact statement that you are confused about? It is still not clear to me what you do, and do not, understand. I not have immediate access to that book.

Comment: @MatthewConroy It is the exact statement, with the example for modulo $8$ (as given in the post, occurring before it in book). To repeat verbatim:-----------       "Certainly, $a\equiv b \pmod 8$ implies $a\equiv b \mod 4$ and $a \equiv b \pmod 2$, but the converse is not true. (Why?) Can you give an example? In general, we cannot reduce a congruence modulo a prime power into smaller moduli. "                    ----------If you could please explain the meaning of the statement, say an example: $3 \equiv 30 \pmod {3^4}$ cannot be reduced to $a' \equiv b' \pmod 3$.

Comment: But $3$ is not congruent to $30$ mod $3^4$.

Comment: @MatthewConroy Sorry, for not considering the example properly. Modified example is: $111\equiv 30\pmod {3^4}.$ I hope a non-constructive proof will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a\equiv b \pmod 8 \iff a \equiv b \pmod4 \wedge a \equiv b \pmod2$

implies that $\mathbb Z_8 \cong \mathbb Z_4 \times \mathbb Z_2$ and this is not true.

\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
x & \mathbb Z_8 & \mathbb Z_4 & \mathbb Z_2 \\
\hline
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
   2 & 2 & 2 & 0 \\
   3 & 3 & 3 & 1 \\
   4 & 4 & 0 & 0 \\
   5 & 5 & 1 & 1 \\
   6 & 6 & 2 & 0 \\
   7 & 7 & 3 & 1 \\
\hline
\end{array}

Note, for example, that $3_8$ and $7_8$ in $\mathbb Z_8$ both correspond to $3_4 \in \mathbb Z_4$ and $1_2 \in \mathbb Z_2$

Comment: I request your help with a question on proof construction. Please respond.

Comment: @jitender Respond how?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I'll take a stab at this, but I'm still not sure what is being asked here.

I think the author is simply saying that the statement $a \equiv b $ mod $p^k$ is **not equivalent** to any statement of the form $a \equiv b$ mod $p^m$ where $m<k$.

The implication goes one direction: $a \equiv b$ mod $p^k$ *implies* that $a \equiv b$ mod $p^m$ for all $m<k$, but the converse is not true, as illustrated by the fact that $2 \equiv 12$ mod $5$ but $2 \not \equiv 12$ mod $25$.

Comment: Please provide a proof, non-constructive, if possible.

Comment: Proof of what?..

Comment: Non-constructive proof for the statement that converse is not possible for moving from congruence for the lower power of prime to the congruence for the higher power of prime, given a set of values for $a,b,p$. I mean that as also indicated by your constructive example, that $2 \equiv 27\pmod 5^2 \implies 2 \equiv 27 \pmod 5$, but not vice-versa, as in the example given by you for $2 \equiv 12 \pmod 5 \nrightarrow  2 \equiv 12 \pmod{5^2}$.

Comment: Why do you care whether the proof is constructive or not?

Comment: Non-constructive proof makes it general, and obvious for all possible complications that can arise. It may need some constructive examples some times to construct a non-constructive proof, but the general framework of a proof is always (even for the simplest problems, that can in turn be taken as a particular example of a general problem) formed by a non-constructive proof.

Comment: Have you tried writing your own proof? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: For the converse, I hope the non-constructive proof, for failure, should be on the lines that for a congruence $a\equiv b\pmod p$ the bigger set of residue classes formed by $p^2$ will not give same residue class as in the lower moduli. For the original statement (i.e. $a\equiv b \pmod{p^2} \implies a\equiv b \pmod p$), the proof approach is even more unclear. I want to add that there can be no help offered by any property based on division in congruences as the modulus is a prime number, and hence co-prime to all.

Comment: Please guide, or tell where my approach should have the next step.

Comment: It may be helpful to note that, for $a$ and $b$ positive integers, if $a<p^m$ and $b<p^m$, then $a \equiv b$ mod $p^m$ only when $a=b$.

Comment: I cannot gather, for $a=2, b=27, p=5,m=2$, it is true that $a\equiv b \pmod {p^m} \implies a\equiv b \pmod p$. But, your condition is wrong, it makes the values of $a,b$ less than the modulus, then anyway for prime or non-prime modulus it is true; as it is a trivial case. Among the residue classes with absolute value taken, what is the meaning of taking values less than modulus, unless it is a trivial example/case.

Comment: Please tell me how the given trivial case is helpful in constructing a proof, as I hope you want to use this as a base condition.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73171/discussion-between-matthew-conroy-and-jitender).

Comment: i request your help for a proof on logic. If you accept the request, then I can proceed.